# List comprehension to make a list of values in a nested dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm given this nested dictionary (albeit a bit longer):

```
stuff = [{'10525083': {'ID': '10525083', 'Score': 25, 'Name': 'Alia Lightside', 'Responses': {'....},
'11004337': {'ID': '11004337', 'Score': 24, 'Name': 'Keebo Keempo', 'Responses': {'....}}]
```

I need to take all the values relating to the 'Score' key and put them in a list... using list comprehension.

I think it should be something like this but I'm really just throwing stones:

```
score = [k, v for v in stuff -something something- append? ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[v.get('Score') for k, v in stuff.items() ]
```

Comment: I tried something like that, I get 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Comment: Never mind, I got it.  scores = [v.get('Score') for k, v in stuff.items()]

Comment: @StealthPython Yep, I forgot to add it.